# How to say "Licensed to" in Portuguese?

Tags: vocabulário

I am producing materials where I own the copyright. I already included the copyright notice, "(c) 2022, all rights reserved."

I would like to further personalize the document and include "Licensed to [licensee name]", in that I grant [Licensee name] the right to use my materials in certain contexts. I do this so that, if the worse comes to worst, another user cannot say "I didn't know I couldn't use this". I used "Licenciado a [nome]" but it sounds wrong.

I am not asking for legal advice. How do I say this in Portuguese?

Comment: Sorry. I thought you had misspelled *license* by saying *licensee*, but it is an actual word. In that case, I would use «Licenciado para [licensee]» if you mean that the person has the authorization to explore it economically. You can say «Licença concedida a [licensee]» either way.

Comment: I like "Licença concecida a ", it seems more explicit then "Licenciado a ". I will change my wording to "Licença de utilização concedida a " to be even more explicit. Can you write an answer?

Comment: Miguelmorin, I believe *uso* is better than *utilização*, as Lambie said. Because *utilizar* means something different, though is synonym of *usar*.

Answer (score 4):

Assinalar os direitos de autor em Portugal costuma ser feito de maneira simples, por exemplo este site da União Europeia resume-o em uma frase

> [Como obter a proteção conferida pelos direitos de autor](https://europa.eu/youreurope/business/running-business/intellectual-property/copyright/index_pt.htm)
>
> No entanto, pode ter de informar outras pessoas de que é o autor da obra em questão. Para isso, pode juntar uma declaração de direitos de autor à sua obra, como a menção «Todos os direitos reservados» ou o símbolo ©, juntamente com o ano de criação da obra.

Pode consultar a lei em pormenor aqui [Decreto-Lei n.º 63/85 - Código do Direito de Autor e dos Direitos Conexos](https://dre.pt/dre/legislacao-consolidada/decreto-lei/1985-34475475) mas se olhar para o rodapé vai ver que a página do Diário da República Electrónico também segue o modelo simples

> INCM, SA - TODOS OS DIREITOS RESERVADOS

Em geral "licensed to" é escrito em português como "licenciada ao (utilizador)" pode ver [um exemplo aqui](https://www.canon.pt/apps/terms_and_conditions/), que tem esta expressão:

> o Software Comercial de Computador e a Documentação de Software Comercial de Computador são licenciados a utilizadores finais dos Estados Unidos ...

Answer (score 3):

"Licença de uso concedida a [nome da pessoa ou empresa]"

The expression in Portuguese is: "conceder uma licença de uso." The verb is "conceder" [grant]. But it's "uso", not "utilização." Here is a reference:

> Cessão e licença de uso: conheça a diferença entre os contratos
>
> Vale
> ressaltar a importância da formalização, por escrito, dos contratos de
> cessão e licença de uso, haja vista que tais instrumentos conterão os
> limites e as condições em que o uso e a exploração da tecnologia
> ocorrerão

[Reference from Contabeis.com.br](https://www.contabeis.com.br/noticias/38888/cessao-e-licenca-de-uso-conheca-a-diferenca-entre-os-contratos/)